# How to enable horizontal scroll in Netbeans 8.2 on Windows with touchpad?

Tags: scroll, netbeans-8

When I scroll up and down with the pad and 2 fingers it is all right. When I do left or right with the pad and 2 fingers it moves the cursor. But I want it to scroll, it scrolls all right by default on MacOS how can I mimic it on Windows 10? I think it is also called `sideways scroll`.

PS

With the mouse `<shift>+scroll` is working all right.

[image]

Comment: [1] There is an open NetBeans bug which might be related to your problem:  [Bug 249339 - horizontal scrolling with touchpad](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=249339). [2] However, since I don't think Oracle is fixing non-critical issues on NetBeans 8.x any more, it might be better to see if the problem is resolved with [NetBeans 9.0](http://netbeans.apache.org/download/index.html). Even if the problem persists you'll have a much better chance of getting a fix with 9.0. [3] I assume you only see this horizontal scrolling problem in NetBeans, right?

Comment: Yes, MS Excel and Google Chrome (as example) are allowing sideways scroll. Thank you.